# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar espacios al principio de una consulta en Laravel 7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

estoy realizando consultas en laravel 7 lo que me a estado causando conflicto son los espacios en blanco, no puedo hacer cambios en la base de datos ya que tengo denegada esa acción, pero tengo la esperanza en realizarlo en la consulta, pero no e podido dar con la solución esta es mi consulta muy básica:

```
        public function allsaicu(Request $request){
        $profesor2 = DB::table('profesores')
        ->select(DB::raw('nombre,apellido_paterno, apellido_materno,rfc, 
        curp,correo,dependencia'))
       ->whereNotNull('correo')
       ->get()->toArray();
       $profesor2 = $this->arrayPaginator($profesor2, $request);
       return view('usuarios.allusers')->with('profesor2',$profesor2);
```

Pero al mostrarla en la vista no se pueden visualizar correctamente ya que los espacios en blanco alteran la consulta de como se deben mostrar.

¿como puedo mostrar la consulta sin espacios en blanco?

Comment: Hola! Por favor NO GRITES :)

Comment: has investigado como eliminar espacion en php?

Comment: asi es con la sentencia TRIM pero esto no me a funcionado ya que los datos siguen igual ya que tienen que ordenarse de manera ASC. es por eso que requiero de su gran ayuda!!!!

Comment: osea tus datos en la base de datos tienen espacios al inicio y al final... tienes algun ejemplo de esta situacion ... tomale una foto o algo por que dependiendo de eso puede que cambie la respuesta...

Comment: si alguna de las respuestas en tus preguntas solucionan tus dudas, recuerda marcaslas como solucionadas.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema de los que se debieron solucionar al inicio del desarrollo y no al momento de hacer consultas.

Si va a hacer una consulta tu clausula `WHERE` debe incluir el `TRIM`:

```sql
SELECT * from tutorials_tbl WHERE TRIM(tutorial_title)='EsteTutorial';
```

es posible que esto no funcione ya que solo eliminara los espacios y caracteres no visibles; otra forma seria con `REPLACE` pero estoy casi seguro que remueve todo los espacios:

```sql
SELECT * from tutorials_tbl WHERE Replace(tutorial_title, ' ', '')='EsteTutorial';
```

Ahora para evitar todo esto puedes sanitizar toda la columna removiendo los espacios segun sea tu necesidad:

- Para reemplazar todos los espacios:

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE(`col_name`, ' ', '')
```

- Para eliminar todos los caracteres de tabulación:

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE(`col_name`, '\t', '' )
```

- Para eliminar todos los caracteres de nueva línea:

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE(`col_name`, '\n', '')
```

[Documentacion REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

- Para eliminar el primer y último espacio(s) de la columna:

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = TRIM(`col_name`)
```

[Documentacion TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

- y si desea eliminar todo tipo de espacios, puede combinar todas estas funciones:

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`col_name`, ' ', ''), '\t', ''), '\n', '');
```

Extracto de esta respuesta en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313886/17161735