# ¿Como eliminar los espacios al recuperar los datos de un formulario?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mvc, crud

espero me puedan ayudar, estoy realizando un Crud. Con PHP y JS, el problema que tengo, es al momento de editar un registro. Los valores me los recupera con espacio, quisiera saber de qué manera puedo recuperar los valores de tal manera que aparezcan de forma correcta, les dejo imagen y código del procedimiento que realizo para recuperar los valores.

[image: Ejemplo de como aparece al momento de recuperar registros]

```js
 var fila; //captura la fila, para editar o eliminar
  //submit para el Alta y Actualización
  $("#formReportes").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //evita el comportambiento normal del submit, es decir, recarga total de la página
    folio = $.trim($("#folio").val());
    nombre = $.trim($("#nombre").val());
    apellido = $.trim($("#apellido").val());
    direccion = $.trim($("#direccion").val());
    descripcion_domicilio = $.trim($("#descripcion_domicilio").val());
    telefono = $.trim($("#telefono").val());
    num_contrato = $.trim($("#num_contrato").val());
    fecha_inicio = $.trim($("#fecha_inicio").val());
    hora_inicio = $.trim($("#hora_inicio").val());
    fecha_final = $.trim($("#fecha_final").val());
    hora_final = $.trim($("#hora_final").val());
    cuadrilla = $.trim($("#cuadrilla").val());
    estatus = $.trim($("#estatus").val());
    observaciones = $.trim($("#observaciones").val());
    encargado_cuadrilla = $.trim($("#encargado_cuadrilla").val());
    otra_descripcion = $.trim($("#otra_descripcion").val());
    $.ajax({
      url: "../controlador/reportes.php",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json",
      data: {
        id: id,
        folio: folio,
        nombre: nombre,
        apellido: apellido,
        direccion: direccion,
        descripcion_domicilio: descripcion_domicilio,
        telefono: telefono,
        num_contrato: num_contrato,
        fecha_inicio: fecha_inicio,
        hora_incio: hora_inicio,
        fecha_final: fecha_final,
        hora_final: hora_final,
        cuadrilla: cuadrilla,
        estatus: estatus,
        observaciones: observaciones,
        encargado_cuadrilla: encargado_cuadrilla,
        otra_descripcion: otra_descripcion,
        opcion: opcion,
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        example1.ajax.reload(null, false);
      },
    });
    $("#modalCRUD").modal("hide");
  });
  
  //para limpiar los campos antes de dar de Alta una Persona
  $("#btnNuevo").click(function () {
    opcion = 1; //alta
    id = null;
    $("#formReportes").trigger("reset");
    $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#224abe");
    $(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
    $(".modal-title").text("Alta Reportes");
    $("#modalCRUD").modal("show");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".btnPrint", function (e) {
    window.open(
      "./../Reports/orden.php?id=" +
        Number(
          e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(
            ".sorting_1"
          ).textContent
        ),
      "_black"
    );
  });

  //Editar
  $(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function () {
    opcion = 2; //editar
    fila = $(this).closest("tr");
    id = parseInt(fila.find("td:eq(0)").text()); //capturo el ID
    folio = fila.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    nombre = fila.find("td:eq(2)").text();
    apellido = fila.find("td:eq(3)").text();
    direccion = fila.find("td:eq(4)").text();
    descripcion_domicilio = fila.find("td:eq(5)").text();
    telefono = fila.find("td:eq(6)").text();
    num_contrato = fila.find("td:eq(7)").text();
    fecha_inicio = fila.find("td:eq(8)").text();
    hora_inicio = fila.find("td:eq(9)").text();
    fecha_final = fila.find("td:eq(10)").text();
    hora_final = fila.find("td:eq(11)").text();
    cuadrilla = fila.find("td:eq(12)").text();
    estatus = fila.find("td:eq(13)").text();
    observaciones = fila.find("td:eq(14)").text();
    encargado_cuadrilla = fila.find("td:eq(15)").text();
    otra_descripcion = fila.find("td:eq(16)").text();
    $("#folio").val(folio);
    $("#nombre").val(nombre);
    $("#apellido").val(apellido);
    $("#direccion").val(direccion);
    $("#descripcion_domicilio").val(descripcion_domicilio);
    $("#telefono").val(telefono);
    $("#num_contrato").val(num_contrato);
    $("#fecha_inicio").val(fecha_inicio);
    $("#hora_inicio").val(hora_inicio);
    $("#fecha_final").val(fecha_final);
    $("#hora_final").val(hora_final);
    $("#cuadrilla option:contains(" + cuadrilla + ")").attr("selected", "");
    $("#estatus option:contains(" + estatus + ")").attr("selected", "");
    //$("#observaciones").val(observaciones);
    $("#observaciones").val($("#observaciones").val().trim());
    $("#encargado_cuadrilla").val(encargado_cuadrilla);
    $("#otra_descripcion").val(otra_descripcion);
    $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#007bff");
    $(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
    $(".modal-title").text("Editar Reporte");
    $("#modalCRUD").modal("show");
  });

  //Borrar
  $(document).on("click", ".btnBorrar", function () {
    fila = $(this);
    id = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text());
    opcion = 3; //eliminar
    var respuesta = confirm("¿Está seguro de borrar el registro " + id + "?");
    if (respuesta) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "../controlador/reportes.php",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { opcion: opcion, id: id },
        success: function () {
          example1.row(fila.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
        },
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Este apartado es el código HTML que utilizo para utilizar mi formulario modal, Realmente desconozco porque me aparece con espacios, incluso pense que mi codigo para recuparar los valores en JS, estaban incorrectos, incluso pense que colando algo como .trim podria solucionarlo, pero realmente desconozco a que se deba el error, si es problema de mi html o de mi JS, aclarando que en la base de datos no tienen espacios.

```html
<!--Modal para CRUD-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCRUD" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title w-100 text-center" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form id="formReportes">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="folio" class="col-form-label">Folio:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="folio" readonly>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label">Nombre</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese un Nombre" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="apellido" class="col-form-label">Apellido</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese un Apellido" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="direccion" class="col-form-label">Dirección</label>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" placeholder="Ingrese una Dirección" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="desc_dom" class="col-form-label">Descripción domicilio</label>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion_domicilio" placeholder="Descripción del Domicilio" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="telefono" class="col-form-label">Telefono</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telefono" placeholder="Numero de telefono" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contrato" class="col-form-label">№ contrato</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="num_contrato" placeholder="Número de contrato" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fecha_incio" class="col-form-label">Fecha de Inicio</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_inicio" placeholder="Ingrese una fecha" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="hora_incio" class="col-form-label">Hora de Inicio</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="num_contrato" placeholder="Número de contrato" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fecha_final" class="col-form-label">Fecha de Finalización</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_inicio" placeholder="Ingrese una fecha" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="hora_final" class="col-form-label">Hora de Finalización</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="fecha_final" placeholder="Ingrese una fecha">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cuadrilla" class="col-form-label">Cuadrilla</label>
                                <select name="cuadrilla" id="cuadrilla" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
                                    <option value="1">Cuadrilla de Operación Ciudad</option>
                                    <option value="2">Cuadrilla de Operación Mega sistema</option>
                                    <option value="3">Cuadrilla de Drenajes</option>
                                    <option value="4">Cuadrilla de Tomas tapadas</option>
                                    <option value="5">Cuadrilla de Cloración</option>
                                    <option value="6">Cuadrilla de Bacheo</option>
                                    <option value="7">Cuadrilla de Contratos</option>
                                    <option value="8">Otros</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="estatus" class="col-form-label">Estatus</label>
                                <select name="status" id="estatus" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option selected>eleccione una opción</option>
                                    <option value="1">Inicio</option>
                                    <option value="2">Pendiente</option>
                                    <option value="3">Terminado</option>
                                    <option value="4">Cancelado</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="observacion" class="col-form-label">Observación</label>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="observaciones" placeholder="Ingrese una Observación"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="encargado" class="col-form-label">Encargado de cuadrilla</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="encargado_cuadrilla" placeholder="Nombre del encargado(a)" require>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="descripcion" class="col-form-label">Otra descripción</label>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="otra_descripcion" placeholder="Otra descripción"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-dark">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el codigo, que utilizo para mi base dedatos. Desconozco que estyo haciendo de forma incorrecta que me aparecen con espacios.

```js
require_once 'conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

//Comprabamos si una variable esta definida o no en el Script
$folio = (isset($_POST['folio'])) ? $_POST['folio'] : '';
$nombre = (isset($_POST['nombre'])) ? $_POST['nombre'] : '';
$apellido = (isset($_POST['apellido'])) ? $_POST['apellido'] : '';
$direccion = (isset($_POST['direccion'])) ? $_POST['direccion'] : '';
$descripcion_domicilio = (isset($_POST['descripcion_domicilio'])) ? $_POST['descripcion_domicilio'] : '';
$telefono = (isset($_POST['telefono'])) ? $_POST['telefono'] : '';
$num_contrato = (isset($_POST['num_contrato'])) ? $_POST['num_contrato'] : '';
$fecha_inicio = (isset($_POST['fecha_inicio'])) ? $_POST['fecha_inicio'] : '';
$hora_inicio = (isset($_POST['hora_inicio'])) ? $_POST['hora_inicio'] : '';
$fecha_final = (isset($_POST['fecha_final'])) ? $_POST['fecha_final'] : '';
$hora_final = (isset($_POST['hora_final'])) ? $_POST['hora_final'] : '';
$cuadrilla = (isset($_POST['cuadrilla'])) ? $_POST['cuadrilla'] : '';
$estatus = (isset($_POST['estatus'])) ? $_POST['estatus'] : '';
$observaciones = (isset($_POST['observaciones'])) ? $_POST['observaciones'] : '';
$encargado_cuadrilla = (isset($_POST['encargado_cuadrilla'])) ? $_POST['encargado_cuadrilla'] : '';
$otra_descripcion = (isset($_POST['otra_descripcion'])) ? $_POST['otra_descripcion'] : '';

$opcion = (isset($_POST['opcion'])) ? $_POST['opcion'] : '';
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

switch ($opcion) {
    case 1:
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO reportes (folio, nombre, apellido, direccion, descripcion_domicilio, telefono, num_contrato, fecha_inicio, hora_inicio, fecha_final, hora_final, cuadrilla, estatus, observaciones, encargado_cuadrilla, otra_descripcion)
        VALUES('$folio','$nombre', '$apellido','$direccion', '$descripcion_domicilio', '$telefono', '$num_contrato', '$fecha_inicio', '$hora_inicio', '$fecha_final', '$hora_final', '$cuadrilla', '$estatus', '$observaciones', '$encargado_cuadrilla', '$otra_descripcion')";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM reportes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;

    case 2:
        $consulta = "UPDATE reportes SET folio='$folio', nombre='$nombre', apellido='$apellido', direccion='$direccion', descripcion_domicilio='$descripcion_domicilio', telefono='$telefono', num_contrato='$num_contrato', fecha_inicio='$fecha_inicio', hora_incio='$hora_inicio', fecha_final='$fecha_final', hora_final='$hora_final', cuadrilla='$cuadrilla', estatus='$estatus', observaciones='$observaciones',
        encargado_cuadrilla='$encargado_cuadrilla', otra_descripcion='$otra_descripcion' WHERE id='$id'";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM reportes WHERE id='$id' ";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;

    case 3: //Eliminar
        $consulta = "DELETE FROM reportes WHERE id='$id' ";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        break;

    case 4:
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM reportes";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;
}

print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //envio el array final el formato json a AJAX
$conexion = null;
```

[image: Base de datos]

[image: BD]

Comment: ya revistaste que en tu base de datos los registros no tengan esos espacios??

Comment: @Gomaru ya revise y esta de manera correcta, no tienen espacio, incluso agregando un nuevo registro me aparece lo mismo

Comment: entiendo por favor podrías agregar el html para poder darte una respuesta mas acertada

Comment: Acabo de agregar el código HTML  @Gomaru

Comment: Cuál es tu base de datos? Y podrías compartir el código correspondiente al backend de ese botón?

Comment: @RoyalUp agrega fotos de mi base de datos, y también agregué el código que es el JS que lo que hace es recuperar los valores al momento de dar clic en editar, te refieres al código de mi Base de datos donde realizo la recuperación de los valores?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 si, al momento de recuperar los valores se quedan con espacios tengo que eliminar esos espacios para poder ver la información.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo eliminar espacios al principio de una consulta en Laravel 7?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558142/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-eliminar-espacios-al-principio-de-una-consulta-en-laravel-7)

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 agrego el codigo

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 agregué el código de mi base de datos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139552/discussion-between-arcanisgk507-and-andres-de-jesus).

Comment: Entra al chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139552/discussion-between-arcanisgk507-and-andres-de-jesus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error consiste en la parte de FrontEnd. Era error del espacio vacío.

```js
<td>
<?php echo $dat['hora_inicio'] ?>
 </td>
```

Código correcto, que me elimina los espacios vacíos.

```js
<td><?php echo $dat['hora_inicio'] ?></td>
```